# GNU Make options. Printing targets and prerequisites

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Hello I was wondering if there is a feature in the linux GNU Make that allows me to print the targets and prerequisites that need to be run without actually running them!  I'm tracing a massive make environment and hoping to get an idea of the flow!  Any other tips would be much appreciated!

ex

```
$ make -option mytarget
making prereq to mytarget
making prereq to prereq
making prereq to prereq to prereq
making mytarget
done..... etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make -n` does a "dry run", printing the commands make *would* run without actually running them.

`make -d` prints out a huge amount of debugging information about how `make` is going about its business and deciding what targets to build and in what order.

You can combine the two too.  You might also like to know about `make -r`, which will quiet down the `make -d` output by not checking any implicit rules, and `make -k` which will make things keep going in the case of an error (which sometimes happens when doing `make -n`, depending on how your makefile is set up):

Relevant parts from the [`make(1)` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make):

> **`-d`**
>   Print debugging information in addition to normal processing.  The
>   debugging information says which files are  being  considered  for
>   remaking,  which  file-times  are  being  compared  and  with what
>           results, which files actually need to be  remade,  which  implicit
>           rules  are considered and which are applied -- everything interesting about how make decides what to do.
>
> **`-k, --keep-going`**
>               Continue as much as possible after an error.  While the target that failed, and those that depend on it, cannot be remade, the other dependencies of these targets  can  be  processed all the same.
>
> **`-n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon`**
>           Print  the  commands  that  would  be executed, but do not execute
>           them.
>
> **`-r, --no-builtin-rules`**
>           Eliminate  use of the built-in implicit rules.  Also clear out the
>           default list of suffixes for suffix rules.

Comment: Awesome thank you!!!!!  I need to get a few more reputation points to select this answer as useful, but I will when I get a chance!

Comment: You can always mark answers on your own questions "accepted", which will give you a small rep bump.